# does not support opening SAP Crystal Reports for Enterprise reports

Tags: java, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-server

copied reports from crystal reports XI to SAP business objects crystal reports 2011.
Trying to run the report and export it as pdf using java.

```
This release does not support opening SAP Crystal Reports for Enterprise reports.---- Error code:-2147467231 [CRSDK00002515] Error code name:notSupported
```

what is difference between crystal reports and enterprise reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal Reports 2011/2013 (CR2013) and Crystal Reports for Enterprise (CRE) are two completely different products. CRE has been built from scratch and the document types of both applications are not interchangeable. It is possible though to convert existing CR2013 documents to CRE (this is a one-way conversion though).

A complete overview of the differences is described in the [SAP Wiki](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/From+Crystal+Reports+2008+to+SAP+Crystal+Reports+2013+or+SAP+Crystal+Reports+for+Enterprise).